# Network FTP access violation with ntdll.dll in windows

Tags: haskell, ftp

I try to test ftp client of [ftphs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ftphs-1.0.9.2/docs/Network-FTP-Client.html) package in windows 7. The test just copy the example from the API document of above link:

```
-- FtpTest.hs
import Network.FTP.Client

main = do h <- easyConnectFTP "ftp.astron.com"
          loginAnon h
          cwd h "/pub/file"
          nlst h Nothing >>= putStrLn . unlines
```

and run

```
runhaskell FtpTest.hs
```

Access violation occurred:

```
Access violation in generated code when reading 0xffffffffffffffff

 Attempting to reconstruct a stack trace...

   Frame        Code address
 * 0x6a7dad8    0x10f38973 C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc
-8.4.2\regex-posix-0.95.2-JzP20x6SHdt1UVPk1SIrSH\HSregex-posix-0.95.2-JzP20x6SHd
t1UVPk1SIrSH.o+0x2881b
                 (regexec+0x1435)
 * 0x6a7dae0    0x10
 * 0x6a7dae8    0x10
 * 0x6a7daf0    0x41a0298
 * 0x6a7dc00    0x776c7974 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+0x27974
 * 0x6a7dc08    0xe120e20
 * 0x6a7dc10    0xf91e1f0
 * 0x6a7dc18    0x1
 * 0x6a7dc20    0x1
 * 0x6a7dc28    0x22
 * 0x6a7dc30    0x776f7584 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+0x57584
 ...
```

Do anyone kwon how to solve it?